# Cannot GET /auth/google/callback | PassportJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

Why I'm getting this error! `Cannot GET /auth/google/callback` after choosing an account from the google login page I got redirected to a white page with the above error, its been a week working on this google login thing!

**This is `index.js` file:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passportSetup = require("./passport");
const passport = require ("passport");

app.use(cookieSession({name: "session", keys: ["mokhtarah"], 
maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100 })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000",
methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
credentials: true,}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

app.listen("4000", () => {
    console.log("Backend is running.");
});
```

**This is the `passport.js` file:**

```
const User = require("./models/User");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");

const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

passport.use(
 new GoogleStrategy(
        {
 clientID: "",
 clientSecret: "",
 callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
        },
 function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)  {
 done(null, profile);
 console.log(profile)
        }
      )
    )
 
 passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
 done(null, user);
    });
 
 passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
 done(null, user);
    });
```

**This is the `auth.js` file:**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const passport = require("passport");
router.get("/google", passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] }))
router.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4000/auth/google'
})
)

//LOGIN WITHOUT PASSPORTJS
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      // if(!user) return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
      !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
  
      const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
      // if(!validated) return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
      !validated && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");
  
      const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
      return res.status(200).json(others);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });
```

Login without passportjs works fine no issues only the google login, I just want the profile data to appear on my console log!

**The Google Cloud Console:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the auth.js file add /auth as a prefix in /google/callback route and in the index.js file remove /api/auth.

**auth.js**

```
router.get('/auth/google/callback', // add **/auth**
  (req,res,next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/google/error' }, async (error, user , info) => {
      if (error){
        return res.send({ message:error.message });
      }
      if (user){
        try {
          // your success code
          return res.send({
            data: result.data,
            message:'Login Successful' 
          });
        } catch (error) {
          // error msg 
          return res.send({ message: error.message });
        }
      }
    })(req,res,next);
  });
```

**index.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const passportSetup = require("./passport");
const passport = require ("passport");

app.use(cookieSession({name: "session", keys: ["mokhtarah"], 
maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100 })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(cors({origin: "http://localhost:3000",
methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
credentials: true,}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use("/", authRoute); // ====> change here
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

app.listen("4000", () => {
    console.log("Backend is running.");
});
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, now i have to change all routes of the app right? like app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);  cause i'm using "proxy": "http://localhost:4000/api" in package.json on the client side but when I change it to "proxy": "http://localhost:4000/" it works fine